# Computational Complexity of Tucker decomposition

Tags: algorithms, mathematics

I am currently doing background reading for my Masters Thesis. I am working with tensor decompositions, whereby tensor I simply mean a multi-dimensional array. The aim of my master's project is to potentially find a new decomposition algorithm or to improve on existing algorithms. So I am quite interested in the computational complexity of decomposition algorithms.

I am reading about the Tucker Decomposition at the moment. The method is simple enough to understand and implement, especially the Higher-Order Orthogonal Iteration(HOOI) Algorithm. However, I am not going to spend a lot of time on this algorithm. So I do not want to include a whole proof and derivation of its computational complexity in my thesis.

Are there references out there that mention or derive the computational complexity of the HOOI algorithm?

Comment: Cross-post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349798/computational-complexity-of-higher-order-orthogonal-iteration-for-tucker-decompo (it's better on the math SE)